# Google Maps v3 geocoding w/ misspelled address

Tags: google-maps

Does the Google Maps API v3 provide a way to access alternate suggestions if the address has typos in it?  For example, I am processing a file containing some misspelled street names and getting 0 results back in the JSON from Google for those addresses.  If I manually search for that address, Google Maps presents me with alternate suggested addresses.  Is there a way to access those with the API in the geocoding response?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: why not use google's standard search api to get spelling suggestions when the geocoding results come back empty?

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into using the custom search API since the standard search API has been deprecated.  I'll need to figure out a way to identify the best match, since the geo-coding occurs during a data load process.